# How to filter out results based off of an Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My program currently has a contenteditable area where users can input text and when they press the button it shoots out the text inputted to another div below it. I am trying to make it so when the user presses the button it shoots out the text inputted but also filters out each div line produced if it contains any of the following words within a specified array.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="pbf-container">
        <div class="pbf-header">
            <h1> VERO Filter Program </h1>
            <h3> Input Links Here </h3>
        </div>
            <div class="pbf-link-container" contenteditable="true">
            </div>
                <div class="pbf-button-control">
                    <button id="pbf-filter"> Filter </button>
                </div>
                    <div class="pbf-link-output">
                    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- uncomment when finished <script src="C:\Users\andrew.lee\Desktop\VERO Filter\pbf.js"></script> -->
    <script>

        $('#pbf-filter').click(function(){
            var $pbfOutput = $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html();
            var pbfFilterWords = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'orange'];
            $('.pbf-link-output').html($pbfOutput)
            .filter(pbfFilterWords).remove('div');
            });


    </script>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#pbf-container {
    display: block;
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 3%;
}

.pbf-header {
    text-align: center;
}

.pbf-link-container {
    width: 1080px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.pbf-button-control {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
}

.pbf-link-output {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VlMN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.each()` to loop through the array and check if `div:contains` any of this .. if yes `.remove()` it .. Actually the bad thing that `contenteditable` div doesn't make the div for the first line .. **BUT** I think I found a solution for this by append an empty `<div>` to the `contenteditable` div

```js
$('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html('<div><br/></div>');
$('#pbf-filter').click(function(){
    var $pbfOutput = $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html();
    var pbfFilterWords = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'orange'];
    $('.pbf-link-output').html($pbfOutput);
    $.each(pbfFilterWords , function(i , val){
        $('.pbf-link-output > div:contains("'+val+'")').remove();
    });

});
```

```css
#pbf-container {
    display: block;
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 3%;
}

.pbf-header {
    text-align: center;
}

.pbf-link-container {
    width: 1080px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.pbf-button-control {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
}

.pbf-link-output {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pbf-container">
<div class="pbf-header">
    <h1> VERO Filter Program </h1>
    <h3> Input Links Here </h3>
</div>
    <div class="pbf-link-container" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
        <div class="pbf-button-control">
            <button id="pbf-filter"> Filter </button>
        </div>
            <div class="pbf-link-output">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful I got it to work, Thanks! Do you have any suggestions or workaround since the contenteditable does not make the first line a div? Maybe have the first line pre filled and not able to edit?

Comment: @Publifiedlabs I found a solution for this .. answer updated

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working as I need it to now. I have upvoted your answer. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: @Publifiedlabs You're Welcome ... Have a great day too :-)